# accepts_nested_attributes_for no Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Caros!

Estou passando um sufoco pois sou novo em Rails.

Estou tentando gerar um form com dois modelos através do Nested Form Rails. É um modelo simples.

"Motor" tem uma ou mais "peças", e "peça" tem somente um "motor". Desta forma fiz os modelos:

```
 class Motor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pecas
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pecas
 end

 class Peca < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :motor
 end
```

O controller de "motors" é :

```
  def new
    @motor = Motor.new
  end



 def create
    @motor = Motor.new(motor_params)
    @motor.pecas.build(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @motor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @motor, notice: 'Motor was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @motor }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @motor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end


private

    def set_motor
      @motor = Motor.find(params[:id])
    end

    def motor_params
      params.require(:motor).permit(:nome, {:peca_attributes => [:item]})
    end
```

Tudo funciona direitinho (QUASE). "Motor" tem um atributo que é nome:string e Peca tem um atributo chamado item:string.

Estou conseguindo gerar um registro de pecas quando gravo um "motor" através da view modificada de "motor" mas não NÃO CONSIGO GRAVAR O NOME DO ATRIBUTO "ITEM" DO MODELO "PECA".

Me parece que é uma nova diretriz do STRONG PARAMETERS no rails 4. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 3):

Incluir no `new` do meu controller

```
def new
  @motor = Motor.new
  @motor.pecas.build   #  Linha incluída
end
```

Na view do objeto `motor`, o objeto `peca` tem que estar pluralizado.

```
<%= form_for(@motor) do |f| %>
      .
      .
      .
<%= f.fields_for :pecas do |peca_build| %>   #  'pecas' TEM QUE ESTAR NO PLURAL
    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <%= peca_build.label :item %>
        <%= peca_build.text_field :item %>
      </p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Na definição dos parâmetros, pluralizar o `attribute`:

```
def motor_params
  params.require(:motor).permit(:nome, {:pecas_attributes => [:item]})   #  'pecas' TEM 
end                                                               #QUE ESTAR NO PLURAL
```

Comment: Poderia marcar sua resposta como aceita?

Answer (score -2):

está faltando colocar no params o campo id

ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
def motor_params
   params.require(:motor).permit(:nome, pecas_attributes: [:id, :item])
end
```

e no método new fica mais ou menos assim:

```
def new
    @motor = Motor.new
    @motor.build_pecas
end
```

com isso pode tirar o build do create